# when making login service with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make login service via Android studio using PHP.

Something goes wrong with my PHP code.

My database's table consists of userID, userPassword, userName, and userNum.

userNum is auto_increment.

Where should I fix my code?

I made my ID, database's name, and password as "".

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
 $userID = $_POST["userID"];
 $userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];
 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE userID = ? AND userPassword = ?");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $userID, $userPassword);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
 mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $userPassword, $userName, $userNum);
 $response = array();
 $response["success"] = false;
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
  $response["success"] = true;
  $response["userID"] = $userID;
  $response["userPassword"] = $userPassword;
  $response["userName"] = $userName; 
  $response["userNum"]=$userNum;
 }
 echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page -> any error ? what is returned by `$userID = $_POST["userID"]; $userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];` when you echo it ? Beside that, **very very very** bad idea storing plain-text passwords ! you should look into PHP built-in function such as `password_hash` [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and `password_verify` [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)`

Comment: @OldPadawan I realized that 'Notice: Undefined index' is returned by $userID = $_POST["userID"]; $userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];.
I'll change the password part after reading password_hash or password_verify carefully. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @OldPadawan why does 'Notice: Undefined index' occur? 
Should I add other things?

Comment: added a more detailed answer, so you can close this :)

Comment: no, just make sure it comes/prints correctly from POST method

Answer (score 0):

As `Notice: Undefined index` is returned by $userID / $userPassword, it means that vars are returning false/empty -> see [PHP variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

> Even if PHP does not require that you declare vars, it's better doing it in order to avoid security breaches (**never ever** trust user's data from inputs) or bugs -> ie: you don't set a value and want to use later.

Therefore, it's a better practice :

- adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and check for errors (it will save huge amount of time).
- always check what is returned by `$_POST / $_GET data;` before using it

> Don't store plain-text passwords -> you should look into PHP built-in function such as `password_hash` [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and `password_verify`  [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)